Is it possible to get a Legendary Boon in the Trial of Salt?
I finished the Trial of Salt on my second try, so I can't retry it, and that Trial's boons seem to be a mix of Poseidon and any of the "Boon-guarantee" Keepsakes if that's worn, since I was wearing the Adamant Shard of Hephestus.
But, if I'd picked my rooms right, could I have finished my Minor Prophecy for getting all of Poseidon's Boons by getting the King Tide Legendary Boon that I'm missing?

According to PCGamesN, only Poseidon boons are available in Trial of Salt.

@pinckerman - At least sometimes you can get others, like this guy got Aphrodite too. https://youtu.be/jNOSwQ4XfyI?t=18

Could that be related to previously acquired Aphrodite's boons?

@pinckerman - Oh, it seems they were wearing the Mirror, so it seems Keepsakes still have effects inside Trials. I was grinding the Adamant Shard and didn't connect it.

According to Hades wiki, in order to get the legendary boon from Poseidon you need a set of required boons:

Wave Strike, Wave Flourish, or Tidal Ring
Breaker Sprint, Fluid Gain, or Geyser Spout
Hydraulic Might, Splash Fount, Slippery Slope, or Flood Control

It's possible to get it from the Trial of Salt since others have, and recently too, it's just that the influence of the Adamant Shard might have stopped you from getting enough Poseidon Boons to luck into seeing it.

Yes, but Chaos Trials (nearly?) don't randomize the Boons offered each go, so even if I had got all 3 requirements, not sure if it still would prevent King Tide.

Added more details to my question and mentioned Hephestus's legendary too, because the further info made not mentioning weird.

Okay, I saw a playthrough of the Trial of Salt that got it, so I'll accept "Yes, it's even likely if you weren't wearing the Adamant Shard".

@Malady feel free to edit my answer accordingly
